# Why is Joda Time serialized form so large, and what to do about it?

Tags: java, serialization, jodatime

On my machine, the following code snippet:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
System.out.println(now);
System.out.println("Date size:\t\t"+serialiseToArray(now).length);
System.out.println("DateString size:\t"+serialiseToArray(now.toString()).length);
System.out.println("java.util.Date size:\t"+serialiseToArray(new Date()).length);
Duration twoHours = Duration.standardHours(2);
System.out.println(twoHours);
System.out.println("Duration size:\t\t"+serialiseToArray(twoHours).length);
System.out.println("DurationString size:\t"+serialiseToArray(twoHours.toString()).length);
```

Gives the following output:

```
2013-09-09T15:07:44.642+01:00
Date size:      273
DateString size:    36
java.util.Date size:    46
PT7200S
Duration size:      107
DurationString size:    14
```

As you can see, the org.joda.time.DateTime object is more than 5 times larger than its String form, which seems to describe it perfectly, and the java.util.Date equivalent. The Duration object representing 2 hours is also much larger than I would expect, as looking at the source it seems like its only member variable is a single `long` value.

Why are these serialized objects so large? And is there any pre-existing solution for getting a smaller representation?

The serialiseToArray method, for reference:

```
private static byte[] serialiseToArray(Serializable s)
{
    try
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayBuffer).writeObject(s);
        return byteArrayBuffer.toByteArray();
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: What `serialiseToArray` method does?

Comment: What it says on the tin. Added implementation to question.

Comment: Java Serialization has lots of self describing padding. A plain Integer uses 80 bytes.  If you wrote the date-time as a long and the timezone as a String it would be 13 bytes long.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Serializing has some overhead. In this instance the overhead that you notice the most is that the class structure is described in the actual output. And since `Duration` has a base class (`BaseDuration`) and two interfaces (`ReadableDuration` and `Serializable`), that overhead becomes slightly larger than the one of `Date` (which has no base class and just a single interface).

Those classes are referenced using their fully-qualified class names in the serialized file and as such create quite some bytes.

Good news: that overhead is only paid once per output stream. If you serialize another `Duration` object, the difference in size should be rather small.

I've used [the jdeserialize project](https://code.google.com/p/jdeserialize) to look in the result of serializing a `java.util.Date` vs. a `Duration` (note that this tool does not need access to the `.class` files, so all information it dumps is actually contained in the serialized data):

The result for `java.util.Date`:

```
read: java.util.Date _h0x7e0001 = r_0x7e0000;
//// BEGIN stream content output
java.util.Date _h0x7e0001 = r_0x7e0000;
//// END stream content output

//// BEGIN class declarations (excluding array classes)
class java.util.Date implements java.io.Serializable {
}

//// END class declarations

//// BEGIN instance dump
[instance 0x7e0001: 0x7e0000/java.util.Date
  object annotations:
    java.util.Date
        [blockdata 0x00: 8 bytes]

  field data:
    0x7e0000/java.util.Date:
]
//// END instance dump
```

The result for `Duration`:

```
read: org.joda.time.Duration _h0x7e0002 = r_0x7e0000;
//// BEGIN stream content output
org.joda.time.Duration _h0x7e0002 = r_0x7e0000;
//// END stream content output

//// BEGIN class declarations (excluding array classes)
class org.joda.time.Duration extends org.joda.time.base.BaseDuration implements java.io.Serializable {
}

class org.joda.time.base.BaseDuration implements java.io.Serializable {
    long iMillis;
}

//// END class declarations

//// BEGIN instance dump
[instance 0x7e0002: 0x7e0000/org.joda.time.Duration
  field data:
    0x7e0001/org.joda.time.base.BaseDuration:
        iMillis: 0
    0x7e0000/org.joda.time.Duration:
]
//// END instance dump
```

Note that the "class declaration" block is quite a bit longer for `Duration`. This also explains why serializing a *single* `Duration` takes 107 bytes, but serializing *two* (distinct) `Duration` objects takes only 121 bytes.

Comment: Good answer. For the record, I reduced the size of the serialized objects by serializing the Duration as a long (using `Duration.getMillis` and `Duration.millis` to convert), and the DateTime as a String (using `DateTime.toString` and `DateTime.parse`). This had no significant performance impact on my program (which reads and writes these objects to files), and decreased the size of my DurationAndDateTime serialised class from 493 bytes to 91 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

From [the source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/joda-time/joda-time/2.2/org/joda/time/DateTime.java#DateTime):

> Internally, the class holds two pieces of data. Firstly, it holds the
>   datetime as milliseconds from the Java epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.
>   Secondly, it holds a Chronology which determines how the millisecond
>   instant value is converted into the date time fields. The default
>   Chronology is org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology which is the agreed
>   international standard and compatible with the modern Gregorian
>   calendar.

The ISOChronology derives from [AssembledChronology](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/joda-time/joda-time/2.2/org/joda/time/chrono/AssembledChronology.java#AssembledChronology), most of which (but not all) is declared as transient fields.

Comment: A `Duration` has no chronology, however.

Comment: Sure. I've not addressed that