# Java Serialization vs Plain text file

Tags: java, file, serialization, io

I'm sort of confused. Let's say I have a game that consists of some tiles and players. All these objects need to be saved so I can later start the game and restore the state. I already do this with simple files like an XML file or plain text files, where I just print the tile type and coordinates into the file and then later read, and parse and create new objects based on the information in the text file.

My question is why should I serialize my objects when I can just save their attributes to a text file? Do many games serialize their objects instea of using text files? Is there any benefit? I could imagine that serializing saves an instance of the object so that you don't have to later create a new instance of the object, like you would have to with a text file. But I really dont know!

Comment: You are serialising your objects.  You're just doing it yourself rather than using a library/framework to do it.

Comment: There's no great advantage to serialization, and it can be quite verbose.  It's best to use some sort of "structured" file, though -- CSV, XML, JSON, etc.  JSON is an attractive choice since there's good tooling to convert from/to Java objects (though a minor learning curve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main benefit of serialization in java is that you don't have to manually do the reading/writting into files, as you are doing now. You just need to implement the [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface and java takes care of it.

Here's a nice tutorial of using serialization in Java: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm

Answer (score 1):

1. I guess serialization will write content in binary format, hence it will consume less 
   space than the corresponding text
2. you can directly get java object from serialized file
3. static variable state will not be saved when using serialization

Comment: Point 1 is highly doubtful, Java serialized objects are usually (always?) larger than a simple custom form (see http://stackoverflow.com/q/18700347/839128). Point 3 is also moot, as a custom serialization like OP's can choose whether it wants to save static fields.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have a version controll via UID.
2. Its Fast.
3. You dont need extra code.